# Updating database from an EditText

Tags: java, android

I have a text field in SQLite database, which I want the user to be able to update.

So I extract and display the text in an EditText view. The user edits it and presses "Update" button. At this point I want to update the text field in database with whatever user has in the EditText.

Here's the problem, EditText returns the type **Editable**.
And the *put(String key, String value)*  function of ContentValues, that I use while updating the record, expects a **String**. So how to put an Editable in a String?

I tried upcasting the Editable to CharSequence and then casting that to String, but that gives me a runtime exception, ClassCastException, which it very well should (because the object was an Editable to begin with, I cannot make it a String).

So how to get around this? Here's the code I am using. I know it is wrong, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   // update logic
   CharSequence strNewName = editTextName.getText();

  //Update record in the table
  ContentValues newRecord = new ContentValues();
  newRecord.put(GIDatabase.Students.NAME, (String strNewName); //ClassCastException here
  int rowsEffected = db.update(GIDatabase.Students.STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME, newRecord, GIDatabase.Students._ID + "=?", new String[]{strId});
if (rowsEffected != 1) {
    // This should never be reached                         
         throw new RuntimeException("Error updating name");
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
String.valueOf(editTextName.getText())
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I later thought of toString() function, but your answer is better (in case of nulls etc).

Comment: toString() is the standard way of doing it that I've seen