# Can't cast from Edit Text to String

Tags: java, android, netbeans-8

EditText entername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enter_name);

// this line convert it to String

```
    String q =entername.getText().toString();
```

//why it is not working in this way ???

```
    String d = (String) entername.getText();
```

Comment: Because in Java you can't cast something to a string if it's not a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating database from an EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770576/updating-database-from-an-edittext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [getText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()) doesn't return a `String`, but an `Editable`.

Note that an `Editable` doesn't extend `String`, but it implements the `CharSequence` interface, so it can be used in many methods that accept `CharSequence`.

Answer (score 0):

Because EditText#getText returns an `Editable`, not a String.